# ejb3 endpoint webservice jboss 7 throws illegalstateexception

Tags: java, web-services, jboss7.x, ejb-3.2

I have a Web service defined as such:

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.example.Test",
        serviceName = "TestWS")
@Stateless
public class TestWS implements Test {
    public final String basic(final int number) {
        return "{\"Basic\":\"true\",\"number\":" + number + "}";
    }
}

@WebService
@Local
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.DOCUMENT)
public interface Test {
    @WebMethod
    public String basic(@WebParam(name = "number")int number);
}
```

and i can see the generated wsdl at [host]/TestWS/TestWS?wsdl, however when i call the webservice (using soapui 5.6.2) it throws an illegalstateexception:

```
08:47:53,209 ERROR [org.jboss.as.webservices.invocation.InvocationHandlerEJB3] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) Method invocation failed with exception: null: java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.jboss.as.webservices.invocation.AbstractInvocationHandlerEJB.getEJBMethod(AbstractInvocationHandlerEJB.java:138)
    at org.jboss.as.webservices.invocation.AbstractInvocationHandlerEJB.invoke(AbstractInvocationHandlerEJB.java:103)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.JBossWSInvoker._invokeInternal(JBossWSInvoker.java:181)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.JBossWSInvoker.invoke(JBossWSInvoker.java:127)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:207)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.RequestHandlerImpl.handleHttpRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:91)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.transport.ServletHelper.callRequestHandler(ServletHelper.java:169)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.invoke(CXFServletExt.java:87)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:185)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:108)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.service(CXFServletExt.java:135)
    at org.jboss.wsf.spi.deployment.WSFServlet.service(WSFServlet.java:140) [jbossws-spi-2.0.3.GA.jar:2.0.3.GA]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
```

can anyone help me solve this? I have tried following the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/JAX-WS+User+Guide) but to no avail.

Comment: Since JBoss 8 is not yet finally released (I see that it entered the release candidate phase), does the same code work on JBoss 7?

Comment: i just checked my JBOSS_HOME parameter and it was infact still pointed to Jboss 7.1.1 final. so this example is actually in version 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [spec](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/websvcs_metadata-2_1-mrel2-eval-spec/), ch. 3.1 "Service Implementation Bean" (emphasis mine):

> The implementation bean MAY reference a service endpoint interface by using the `@WebService.endpointInterface` annotation. [...] In this case, the **service implementation bean MUST NOT include any JSR-181 annotations other than `@WebService` and `@HandlerChain`**.

So could you try removing the `@WebMethod` annotation from the method in the *class* (the annotation in the *interface* method should suffice) **and** moving the `@SOAPBinding` to the interface?

---

Additionally the EJB method is marked `final`. This is probably the problem ([ref](https://community.jboss.org/thread/205646)).

Comment: i made the changes you suggested, but it still gives me that error.

Comment: Hi, could you check the edit and the [link](https://community.jboss.org/thread/205646)? I think this is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI for anyone that ends up here, I also got this error with and EJB/WS method that was accidentally declared as static.